# Getting keyboard usage codes, how to send trigger from read()

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4, raspberry-pi

I wrote a test in Qt to get keyboard USB usage codes, basically "scancodes", but a little more raw.

I'm using a modified version of **showkey.c** that I converted to C++, classed it and all that. For reference the heart of it is

```
n = read(fd, &buf, sizeof(buf));
if (n == -1) { cout << "ERROR READING USAGE CODE"; clean_up(fd); return n; }
clean_up(fd);
close(fd);
return buf[0];
```

At this point **read()** is listening to the USB port, sends back all usage codes and all good. It sends back a 64 bit integer in buf[0] with entire usage code list, but I decode it, and put in a vector (good or bad, this does work)
The problem and whole point of this rambling post is, the GUI is stuck while it is waiting on a keypress. So need a trigger INSIDE **read()**? If I was reading a text file, could to the trigger after each line.

For additional reference
The GUI is small buttons in shape of whole keyboard, and the operators are pressing each key in order, and color of button is changing to green as they go. So GUI isn't exactly frozen, just can't click an abort test or something until either the current test passes of fails.

This may not be as clear as I would like it to be, but can read be extended somehow?

The test stations are using Raspberry machines, Qt C++ code and Rasbian Linux. Have 10 raspberry and ultimately will be robotic.

Comment: Could you move port listening to new thread? That would keep GUI thread  free, and threads interaction in Qt is fairly easy.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what the question is, but maybe you need to open the file descriptor as non-blocking: `fd =  = open(KEYBOARD_DEV, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);`, where `KEYBOARD_DEV` is the fd for the keyboard (in my case `"/dev/input/event3"`). Or alternatively spawn a thread reading the keyboard input.

Comment: Oh I should have mentioned, I have tried threading it, but the read() seems to still take all control until a key is pressed.  And thanks for input. I tried O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK,  but have to use only O_RDWR or it fails.

Comment: @Dan What fails?/How does it fail? I have previously used `O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK` to make a "non-blocking keyboard reader" that can be poll'ed for keyboard input in a non-threaded environment. Threading the code `read` will still block if you have not opened it in a non-blocking state, but it will only block the thread calling `read`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for input. I had some fundamental misunderstandings of threads and triggers. Working it out